# Class cannot access its Companion object. (with import and class name)

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I know a companion object is nothing but singleton object with same class name. If a singleton object is just like using static methods, that means I should be able to access its methods without creating an instance in the class. The following is my code snippet:

```
class Main {

  import Main._

  def sayHelloWorld() {
    println("Hello World");
  }

  Main.sayHi //error
}

object Main {
  def sayHi() {
    println("Hi!");
  }
}
```

Question 1. Why I am not able to access the companion object's method (though I have specified the import)?

Question 2: How can I use the object name and access it directly without importing?

Comment: Where does `test` come from?

Comment: "Question 1. Why I am not able to access the companion object's method (though I have specified the import)?" You can. Please post the actual code you are using. `test` isn't declared, and there's no call to sayHiI() in your code. If there was (in class Main) it would work

Comment: Thank you!
The actual problem was I was not binding both with an object.
(REPL)

Comment: additional Info:
Because the companion object and the class must be defined in the same source file you cannot create them in the interpreter.
source: daily-scala
work around: bind both with some object in REPL

Comment: You can create them in the REPL, but you need to do so as part of a single `:paste` command (type `:help` for a list of REPL commands).

Answer (score 4):

Since you're provided code that won't compile for other reasons, it's difficult to guess what problems you were having. But assuming you meant this:

```
  class Main {

    import Main._

    def sayHelloWorld() {
      println("Hello World")
    }
    sayHi()
  }

  object Main {
    def sayHi() {
      println("Hi!")
    }
  }
```

then this calls `sayHi()` in the companion object

```
val m = new Main();                               //> Hi!
```

Comment: Yes sorry that test shouldnt have been in the code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was I was not binding them both with another object. (REPL)
Additional Info: Because the companion object and the class must be defined in the same source file you cannot create them in the interpreter. 
source: daily-scala 
work around: bind both with some object in REPL
or as user #shadowlands said
You can create them in the REPL, but you need to do so as part of a single :paste command (type :help for a list of REPL commands)